# Angular 2 template selector not known

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to perform a simple template injection into a page, but I receive the following error at run time in the console window of chrome :

> zone.js:388 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
>   'recruiter-detail' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'recruiter-detail' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'recruiter-detail' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>      to suppress this message. ("[ERROR
>      ->]"): AppComponent@0:0 ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:(…)
>      Error: Template parse errors: 'recruiter-detail' is not a known
>      element:
> 3. If 'recruiter-detail' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RecruiterDetailsComponent } from "./recruiter/recruiter-details.component";

@Component({
    selector: 'pm-app',
    template: `<recruiter-detail></recruiter-detail>`
})
export class AppComponent {
    pageTitle: string = 'Agent details';
```

**recruiter-details.component.ts**  this resides in a subfolder called recruiter

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'recruiter-detail',
    templateUrl: './app/recruiter/recruiter-details.component.html'
})
export class RecruiterDetailsComponent {
}
```

I'm using VS2015. under my wwwroot folder I have an app folder where main.ts, app.component.ts and app.module.ts reside. app has a subfolder of recruiter.

Comment: Show us your app module , you've probably forgotten to declare RecruiterDetailsComponent in you app module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If 'recruiter-detail' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module

Did you add your recruiter-detail component in declarations section in your module.ts

Also the error says promise rejection.

Look at your code once more, There are probably errors in the template.

Try adding your component to declarations in module.ts
If it does not work 
look at how you are handling the promise and also look at the template for errors or typos

Comment: No I haven't. I declared it as in import to app.component.ts so didn't think I'd need to. I'll add it now and see what happens

Comment: That has removed the above error. I now receive the following one :     `http://localhost:57703/recruiter/recruiter-details.component.html 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: you gave the path to your recruiter-details.component‌​.html wrong

Comment: if they are in the same folder try 
./../recruiter/recruiter-details.component‌​.html

Comment: basically the structure is wwwroot/app/recruiter. in recruiter there is a recruiter-details.component.html a recruiter-details.component.ts file. at wwwroot/app I have app.component.ts app.module.ts and main.ts

Comment: I tried your relative path, but I still receive the same error

Answer (score 1):

Try by changing template url like

**templateUrl: 'app/recruiter/recruiter-details.component.html'**

instead of

templateUrl: './app/recruiter/recruiter-details.component.html'

Comment: Yay this solved the second issue. Thank you. I could have sworn I tried this already,